# NSTimer no effect...?

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nstimer, appkit

I tried to call [self setNeedsDisplay:YES] in a NSTimer selector in order to trigger the drawRect method.

At first, I put the NSTimer init code in a button func:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPush:(id)sender
{
   myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
    target:self
  selector:@selector(myTimerAction:)
  userInfo:nil
  repeats:YES];
}

-(void)myTimerAction:(NSTimer *) timer
{  
[self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

The "setNeedsDisplay" is called normally but the code inside the drawRect is never called:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect 
{
NSLog(@"drawRect");
}
```

Then I tried to move the NSTimer init code to "- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame", then everything works just fine.
(the drawRect is called correctly every 1 sec).

What's the difference between the two methods above? 
What should I do if I want to trigger the Timer in a button?

Comment: From the description everything should just work fine. There's no bug or anything hinting at what's going wrong. The bug is elsewhere. You have to post more context or code.

Comment: I assume that you did not forget to connect the action to your button? Try putting an NSLog statement in your `-buttonPush:` method and see if it is output.

Answer (score 1):

Just wondering, in what class does that code reside? I would assume the *buttonPush:* action is inside a controller, correct?

If so, then you should have:

```
-(void)myTimerAction:(NSTimer *) timer
{
  [[self view] setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

because setNeedsDisplay: is a method of *NSView*, not *NSViewController*.

(BTW probably the reason why it works if you put it inside *initWithFrame:* is because that one is a *NSView* initializer: I'm guessing that when you move the code there you are also moving the *myTimerAction:* method, which then has "*self*" referring correctly to the view.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the class code is in a NSView and if I try to change the code to "self view" I'll get an error:".....not responding to -view"

Comment: Not sure I follow anymore. Probably restating the obvious, but to make sure we are on the same page: put buttonPush: and myTimerAction: in your View Controller. Leave drawRect: inside your custom view. For the myTimerAction implementation use my code above, that references [self view]

Answer (score 0):

Since it works when you use initWithFrame:, the problem is probably that buttonPush: isn't hooked up correctly. Try setting a breakpoint in buttonPush: an see if it is actually called when you click the button.

Comment: The OP already confirmed that [self setNeedsDisplay:] does get executed.